# Get rid of rotation point | Blender

Tags: error

I am creaiting objekt and I have trouble with rotating. When it rotates, **the object rotates around some point**, I need to get rid of this point.  Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm only now learning Blender (2.83) but this was covered by the tutorial sequence I viewed yesterday.

This may not be the only answer, but it's one of them.

You cannot "remove" or get rid of the pivot. It appears that your pivot is at the bottom of the black dotted line to the left of the object. Every selected object has one. You can place it to a more convenient or useful location, however.

Place your 3D cursor where you would like the object pivot. (Shift Right Mouse Button)

In the layout viewport (I can't tell which viewport you are using), select Object, Origin, Set Origin to 3D Cursor. You'll see the small circle become coincident with the 3D cursor and rotations will now happen about that center.

[image: menus for pivot relocation]

Comment: You normally want to use 'Set origin to geometry' on that menu,

Comment: That's a superior method, thanks!